# how can i count this 3 fields in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
CASE    
WHEN EPro02.StartReportID = 101 AND EventProvider02.StartVoltage = 0 THEN 'Power Supply Disconnected'

WHEN EventProvider02.StartSatelliteCount < 9 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMSignalLevel < 20 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMStatus != 9 THEN 'Network Outage'

WHEN EventProvider02.StartReportID = 13 THEN 'GSM Jamming'

END AS Reason
```

Comment: Could you please frame your question more clearly?

Comment: I want a count of 'Power Supply Disconnected','GSM Jamming' and 'Network Outage' individually.

Answer (score 0):

Use your entire `CASE...END` with `count()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
CASE    
WHEN EPro02.StartReportID = 101 AND EventProvider02.StartVoltage = 0 THEN 'Power Supply Disconnected'
WHEN EventProvider02.StartSatelliteCount < 9 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMSignalLevel < 20 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMStatus != 9 THEN 'Network Outage'
WHEN EventProvider02.StartReportID = 13 THEN 'GSM Jamming'
END AS Reason, 
count(CASE    
WHEN EPro02.StartReportID = 101 AND EventProvider02.StartVoltage = 0 THEN 'Power Supply Disconnected'
WHEN EventProvider02.StartSatelliteCount < 9 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMSignalLevel < 20 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMStatus != 9 THEN 'Network Outage'
WHEN EventProvider02.StartReportID = 13 THEN 'GSM Jamming'
END) as Reason_count
FROM your_table_join_here
GROUP BY CASE    
WHEN EPro02.StartReportID = 101 AND EventProvider02.StartVoltage = 0 THEN 'Power Supply Disconnected'
WHEN EventProvider02.StartSatelliteCount < 9 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMSignalLevel < 20 OR EventProvider02.StartGSMStatus != 9 THEN 'Network Outage'
WHEN EventProvider02.StartReportID = 13 THEN 'GSM Jamming'
END
```